# Bash completion appends a space after a word - how can I stop this?

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, autocomplete

I'm writing a tab completion script for Bash, using Python to deliver the results of the completion. I'm using a dummy script to show the problem I'm having, the content is not important.

I've got a Bash script called `dothat`, with the following code:

```
var=$1
echo "You have chosen $var"
```

I've also got a script which creates the tab-completion for `dothat`, called `dothat-completion.bash`:

```
_comp_func()
{
    COMPREPLY=()

    # Gets the output of a Python file and puts it into a variable
    fruits=$(python fruit.py)

    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${fruits[*]}" -- $cur)) 
}

complete -F _comp_func dothat
```

And the (simple) content of `fruit.py`:

```
print('fruit:', end='')
```

The Python script just prints the string to STDOUT, and this is then captured by the Bash completion function, and used to generate possible matches for tab completion.

Now, what I want to do with this script is, when I type `dothat <TAB>`, it will then complete to `dothat fruit:`, with no space on the end. The problem is, when I type `dothat`  and press tab, it completes to `dothat fruit:` , with the unwanted trailing space.

I've tried changing the contents of the Python to the following, and all with the same result:

```
print('"fruit:"', end='')
print("'fruit:'", end='')
print('fruit:', end='')
print("fruit:", end='')
print("fruit: ", end='')
print("fruit:          ", end='')
print('fruit')
```

Even:

```
foo='fruit'
print(foo)
```

And all of my attempts are fruitless, as they achieve the same result. It doesn't matter whether there are zero, one or twenty spaces on the string: if the Python outputs the string `fruit:` and feeds it back into the Bash completion script, `compgen` will decide to complete `fruit:`  with a space.

Is there an obvious solution here that I've missed? For either the Bash or the Python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for `complete` when a full match is found, to append a space and allow further typing into the line, indicating that this word has been completed. And here you have only one word into `COMPREPLY`, so after <kbd>TAB</kbd> you get this word completed.

To overrride this default behavior, you could use `-o nospace`. From `man bashbuiltins`:

> **nospace** Tell readline not to append a space (the default) to words
> completed  at  the end of the line.

Comment: Perfect, that solves the problem! Thank you!

Comment: How can I use the `nospace` option only for a sub set of completions though?